# Differenze tra i costrutti "è dato di" + infinito e "è dato" + infinito

Tags: word-usage, difference, prepositions

Nel romanzo *Non so niente di te* di Paola Mastrocola, pubblicato da Einaudi,  ho letto (il corsivo è mio):

> Chi fosse insomma il colpevole - e se fosse il caso d'individuare sempre, anche per le cause naturali piú naturali e imprevedibili, un colpevole -, non *era dato sapere*.

L'espressione "era dato sapere" in questa frase ha subito attirato la mia attenzione perché io avevo sempre pensato che fosse necessario usare la preposizione "di" prima dell'infinito "sapere". Infatti, cercando su Internet, ho trovato esempi di uso della costruzione verbo "essere" + "dato di" + infinito

> - Non a tutti è dato di fare un bambino al momento opportuno
> - Non ci è dato di guardare oltre la piccola licenza per la ristrutturazione del bagno
> - A quanto mi è dato di capire

ma anche di verbo "essere" + "dato" + infinito senza la preposizione "di"

> - Quanto è dato sapere sulla beccaccia e dintorni
> - Non era dato riscontrare nel contratto quell'elemento essenziale
> - Non era dato conoscere l'andamento futuro dei tassi

La mia domanda è: qual è la differenza tra questi due costrutti? Quando e quando non si deve usare la preposizione "di"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Entrambe le forme sono corrette e utilizzabili, praticamente con lo stesso significato.
Usare l'una o l'altra è una questione più che altro di gusto personale e di stile.
Direi che la forma senza preposizione *di* è più usata, come testimonia anche una [ricerca sull'Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%C3%A8+dato+sapere&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%C3%A8%20dato%20sapere%3B%2Cc0) di Google Books.

Answer (score 0):

La presenza del "di" all'interno del costrutto verbale in questione ha una sottointesa funzione comparativa che invece non è presente nella frase verbale priva della preposizione. Proverò ad illustrare il concetto usando le frasi di esempio sopra riportate.

> - Non a tutti è dato di fare un bambino al momento opportuno, ma a tutti è dato di provarci.
> - Non ci è dato di guardare oltre la piccola licenza per la ristrutturazione del bagno, e neppure di sapere quando potremo farlo.
> - A quanto mi è dato di capire, ma non di sapere.

Da madrelingua italiano quale sono, omettendo il "di" nella prima frase di ciascuna proposizione, percepisco le tre proposizioni che seguono come grammaticalmente incomplete.

> - ** Non a tutti è dato fare un bambino al momento opportuno, ma a tutti è dato di provarci*.
> - ** Non ci è dato guardare oltre la piccola licenza per la ristrutturazione del bagno, e neppure di sapere quando potremo farlo*.
> - ** A quanto mi è dato capire, ma non di sapere*.

Naturalmente il senso di incompletezza sintattica svanisce qualora solo la prima frase di ciascuna proposizione sia presente. In conclusione, la presenza o l'assenza del "di" nella costruzione verbale non cambia tanto il significato della frase in sé, ma restringe le aspettative su come può continuare il discorso a partire dalla frase in questione - qualora il discorso dovesse continuare, beninteso.
Rimuovendo la preposizione "di" da entrambe le frasi verbali, le proposizioni tornano a essere percepite come grammaticali (ad eccezione della terza).

> - Non a tutti è dato fare un bambino al momento opportuno, ma a tutti è dato provarci.
> - Non ci è dato guardare oltre la piccola licenza per la ristrutturazione del bagno, e neppure sapere quando potremo farlo.
> - ** A quanto mi è dato capire, ma non sapere*.

Comment: Benvenuto su Italian.SE e grazie della risposta! Non capisco molto bene: vuoi dire che nelle tre ultime frasi c'è qualcosa che non va?

Comment: Che intendi per “sottointesa funzione comparativa”? Potresti parafrasare il significato di una delle frasi con e senza il “di”?

Comment: Mi aggiungo anch'io al gruppo di quelli che non riescono a capire la differenza tra le frasi *con il di* e *senza il di*.

Comment: Salve a tutti, ho provato a riformulare la risposta. Spero sia più chiara. Non dovesse esserlo fatemi sapere!

Comment: Forse non capisco ancora bene. Le frasi del secondo esempio sono senz'altro incomplete, ma perché in ognuna nella seconda parte c'è un “di” e nella prima no. Tu percepisci come incompleta anche, per esempio, «Non a tutti è dato fare un bambino al momento opportuno, ma a tutti è dato provarci» (senza nessuno dei due “di”)?

Comment: Nel secondo gruppo di esempi c'è un "di" solo nella prima parte per far capire che se manca il "di" nella prima parte è strano trovarlo invece nella seconda parte. La frase «Non a tutti è dato fare un bambino al momento opportuno, ma a tutti è dato provarci» (senza nessuno dei due “di”) è a mio parere corretta. Grazie del contributo.